# JCas type ...Timex3... used in Java code, but was not declared in the XML type descriptor heideltime

Tags: java, nlp, uima, uimafit, heideltime

I configured heidelTime using gradle. I am getting values however cannot iterate over the string result.

```
result = heidelTime.process(sentence, new Date());
JCas cas = JCasFactory.createJCas();
FSIterator it = cas.getAnnotationIndex(Timex3.type).iterator(); // Here I am getting error
```

Error is due to **JCasImpl.class->TOP_Type getType(int i)**

```
if (this.casImpl.getTypeSystem().getType(typeName) == null) {
            // no - report error that JCAS type was not defined in XML
            // descriptor
            CASRuntimeException casEx = new CASRuntimeException(
                CASRuntimeException.JCAS_TYPE_NOT_IN_CAS, new String[] { typeName });
            throw casEx;
          }
```

I checked on github project and I see HeidelTime_TypeSystem.xml files there defining type System.

**Gradle Configuration**

```
compile group: 'com.github.heideltime', name: 'heideltime', version: '2.2.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.uima', name: 'uimaj-core', version: '2.3.1'
```

**Stack Trace**

```
org.apache.uima.cas.CASRuntimeException: JCas type de.unihd.dbs.uima.types.heideltime.Timex3" used in Java code,  but was not declared in the XML type descriptor.
            at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getType(JCasImpl.java:412) ~[uimaj-core-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
            at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getCasType(JCasImpl.java:436) ~[uimaj-core-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
            at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getAnnotationIndex(JCasImpl.java:1531) ~[uimaj-core-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
```

**Do I need to add any files manually to make it work?**

**types.txt file location**

[image]

Comment: I get this kind of error normally when I forget to add the type system description in the types.txt file. Can you check if jcas.getTypeSystem() contains the type? Do you have a type.txt file specifying the heideltime type system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when a JCas class for an UIMA type is being used without the CAS being configured for this type.

The call to

```
JCas cas = JCasFactory.createJCas();
```

scans the classpath for files called `types.txt` under `META-INF/org.apache.uima.fit/` (so a folder called `META-INF` with a subfolder called `org.apache.uima.fit` which then contains the `types.txt` file) and loads all the UIMA type descriptors referenced inside them. An example `types.txt` file looks like this:

```
classpath*:org/apache/uima/fit/type/Token.xml
```

This tells uimaFIT to load the type descriptor file `Token.xml` located in the package `org.apache.uima.fit.type` (replace with your own package and file names).

Note that if you use Maven, these all these files and folders must usually be under `src/main/resources` (not under `src/main/java`). Depending on how you set up your Gradle, this might apply to you as well.

uimaFIT's type auto-detection is also described in more detail in the [uimaFIT documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/tools.uimafit.book.html#ugr.tools.uimafit.typesystem).

So for your particular case: try putting `desc/type/HeidelTime_TypeSystem.xml` into `src/main/resources/desc/type/HeidelTime_TypeSystem.xml` and create the `src/main/resources/META-INF/org.apache.uima.fit/types.txt` file  with the content `classpath*:desc/type/HeidelTime_TypeSystem.xml`.

*Note: At the time of writing, I am the maintainer of Apache uimaFIT.*

Comment: I have project setup as gradle build, and I don't find the location as that of listed on doc, I have updated question with screenshot of where I posted in gradle project but no luck

Comment: The location of the `types.txt` file looks good. What is the content of the file? And where is the type descriptor XML file which contains the definition of `de.unihd.dbs.uima.types.heideltime.Timex3` located?

Comment: classpath*:/home/julian/heideltime/heideltime-kit/desc/type/HeidelTime_TypeSystem.xml

Comment: That doesn't seem like a classpath-relative location. Try putting `desc/type/HeidelTime_TypeSystem.xml` into `src/main/resources/desc/type/HeidelTime_TypeSystem.xml` and using `classpath*:desc/type/HeidelTime_TypeSystem.xml` in the `types.txt` file.

Comment: I updated the main answer with the text from my previous comment.